# how to make an virtual chat bot in java?

Tags: java, chat, bots, chatbot, aiml

I want to make an chat bot in Java but I don't know how to start?
I've tried the following code but not get what I exactly need.
in this program I had to write every possibilities of questions.
if any one have solution please help me.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Chatbot 
{
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException
{
    String hel = new String("Hello");
    String hel1 = new String("HELLO");
    String hel2 = new String("hello");
    String hel3 = new String("Hii");
    String hel4 = new String("Hiii");
    String hel5 = new String("hii");
    String hel6 = new String("hiii");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("What is Your Name?");
        String name = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Hello "+name+"..");
        String hellorep = br.readLine();
        if(hellorep .equals(hel))
        {
            System.out.println("Hello there...");
        }
        else if(hellorep .equals(hel1))
        {
            System.out.println("Hello there...");
        }
        else if(hellorep .equals(hel2))
        {
            System.out.println("Hello there...");
        }
        else if(hellorep .equals(hel3))
        {
            System.out.println("Hii");
        }
        else if(hellorep .equals(hel4))
        {
            System.out.println("Hiii");
        }
        else if(hellorep .equals(hel5))
        {
            System.out.println("Hii");
        }
        else if(hellorep .equals(hel6))
        {
            System.out.println("Hiii");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Please type Again I Didn't get you..");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make this with a window you can use a jtextfield and add a actionlistener to it and if you want to make this with the console then use a input

then get the message aka store it in a variable and then do this in your respond method

`if(STRINGVARIABLENAME.contains("Your word that you want it to check if it contains")) {
then make the bot respond by Console or just do JTEXTFIELDNAME.setText("ANSWER HERE")
}`

and add as many response possibilities by doing a else if after the if like this

`if(){
} else if(STRINGVARIABLENAME.contains("")){
}`

you can do this as many times as you want and there you have your chat bot :D